Create faces (fill) between multiple vertices
I would like to create a face at the selected edge. I don't really know how it works because "F" creates the bad face on the right side.
Does anybody have an idea?
My goal is to make the middle part of the robot arm in this picture.

My mesh looks like this: Left: Create a face here. Right: That's not what I want..

This is my blend file: https://we.tl/t-jGWOEGogYD
Don't know how to attach it here, sorry!
Thank you in advance!

did u try just press F instead of bridge edge loops?

@Chris Yes, that was the only thing i tried.

You should work with less vertices, it would make it simpler to modify.
First thing select all and press ShiftN to recalculate the normals (because half of them are inverted), then fill with F and inset twice with i. As the inner face is coplanar with the adjacent faces, there won't be bad shading:

Bevel the edge if you want it sharper:


Thank you so much! Do you know a smart way to reduce vertices?
What made my normals that bad and what consequence does it have if I recalculate them? Thank you!

You had inverted normals (open the Viewport Overlays panel, activate the Face Orientation option and you will see them), you can't reduce the amount of faces with a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide because it will mess up the topology so I guess you need to do it manually, it's always better to work on a low-poly mesh if possible, and give it a Subdivision Surface modifier to make it rounder, apply the modifier at the end if it's really necessary
